# Why is my code showing heap buffer overflow

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the title of the [Leetcode 2367](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-arithmetic-triplets/description/). The number of arithmetic triples
Gives you an array of integers `nums` with a subscript starting at 0 and strictly increasing and a positive integer `diff`. A triplet`(i, j, k)`is an arithmetic triplet if all of the following conditions are met:
`i < j < k ，`
`nums[j] - nums[i] == diff` 
`nums[k] - nums[j] == diff`

this is my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    int arithmeticTriplets(vector<int>& nums, int diff) {
        int ans = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; i < nums.size() - 1; j++) {
                if (nums[j] - nums[i] == diff) {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.size(); k++) {
                        if (nums[k] - nums[j] == diff) ans++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
};
```

But I couldn't pass the assessment
show that
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x503000000090 at pc 0x558615c49233 bp 0x7fffb82e42b0 sp 0x7fffb82e42a8

Comment: All of those nested loops, I'm really surprised you didn't get a TLE message from Leetcode.

Comment: `for (int j = i + 1; i < nums.size() - 1; j++)` Why is this loop different from all other loops?

Comment: @Chris The constraints are very low; the length of the array is at most 200, so O(n^3) easily passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second level loop, you never test the value of `j`, and since `i` is not updated, it can continue looping until `nums[j]` results in an out of bounds memory access.

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++) {
>             for (int j = i + 1; i < nums.size() - 1; j++) {
>                 if (nums[j] - nums[i] == diff) {
>                     for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.size(); k++) {
>                         if (nums[k] - nums[j] == diff) ans++;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

You *probably* wanted:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size() - 1; j++)
```